# JavaScript type checking and exceptions in the context of Prototype constructors?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, prototype

I'm building my first open-source JavaScript library as a node module, it's solving a very simple problem and thus it's a very simple module, specifically, it is a single prototype object.

To offer context, I'm from a purely web-tech background and only in the past year have I started to look into other languages, falling in love with statically typed, truly OOP and class-oriented languages and I'm beginning to see the breadth of pros and cons for the languages on either side of the camp.

As far as I understand, when constructing a *class* with class-oriented you should `return nil` to specify that construction has failed allowing a user to check with `if(instance === nil)` for it's success. Alternatively I've seen `return 421` for example to provide an error code, I then also assume some also return string e.t.c. **But importantly,** I've seen that you **shouldn't** throw an exception.

Is this correct? Also what are the reasons for that? Is this also a problem with prototype-oriented languages or does javascript's dynamic nature make it acceptable?

This leads onto my next question, I've seen a lot of javascript libraries over the years, had a tinker and whatnot. I've found that it's rare to not only to build prototypes in an OOP-ish pattern but it's also rare to come across any frequently implemented type detection or type checking, many people are relying on the convenience of the dynamic typing to offer that productivity boost, but I'd like to mix up the pros and cons of each type system by starting with dynamically typed but also introduce a more stable architecture using some statically typed patterns and methodologies.
To get to the point, is it an acceptable (or even good?) practice to heavily type check javascript scripts? I would love to add serious type checking code to my prototypes constructor and methods but as it's an open-source project I'm worried how the community will approach it, would they want it to be more dynamically typed? I can only assume many people use dynamically typed languages for their... uhh.. dynamic typing, but its worth a ponder.

**DISCLAIMER**
I <s>understand</s> *have seen* that many people say javascript is "untyped" rather than "dynamically" typed, but using dynamic purely for its proliferation.

**TLDR-Q1:** Can I throw exceptions in constructor methods? What about in javascript prototypes? Why!? How should I handle it?

**TLDR-Q2:** Can I introduce heavy type checking and throw exceptions to give javascript scripts a poor mans static type? Do developers like this? Am I being ignorant and this a really common thing?

Comment: Yes, throwing exceptions from constructor functions seems pretty much established - regardless whether the language is class- or prototype-based. Can you please link to a source that says you shouldn't do this?

Comment: It's your library, just use whatever you need to make it work as you want. Open source doesn't mean you must do what others want.

Comment: Yes, doing typechecks and throwing helpful exceptions is totally fine in JavaScript. But notice that you should use duck typing for that, instead of nailing down objects to a specific class.

Comment: If you want to truly *statically* typecheck javascript, not only dynamically, there exist tools for that as well. Have a closer look at them, e.g. Flow.

Comment: You could use a static type checker like flow.

Comment: @valarauko - I came across Flow and it is what made the initial connection of 'oh wait these can totally benefit each other'. I use it but I'm definitely more interested in implementing the static type checking into the script to increase stability e.t.c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> TLDR-Q1: Can I throw exceptions in constructor methods? What about in
>   javascript prototypes? Why!? How should I handle it?

Yes, you can throw exceptions in a constructor.  If truly invalid arguments have been passed, then that is probably the cleanest way to do things.

I, myself, would not generally design an expected path of the code to throw an exception, but would instead reserve it for the type of error that probably signifies bad data or wrong usage by the programmer.  Exceptions get logged nice and cleanly in the debug console and are one of the quickest ways to communicate to someone using your constructor that they've messed up as it will get logged and you can put a nice descriptive message in the error object when you throw and the developer gets a stack trace.

Returning `null` is not such a clean or helpful way and adds code the developer probably doesn't normally need to check for `null` all the time.

> TLDR-Q2: Can I introduce heavy type checking and throw exceptions to
>   give javascript scripts a poor mans static type? Do developers like
>   this? Am I being ignorant and this a really common thing?

You can write Javascript type checking as much as you need.  IMO, you should only do so when you're trying to determine if an argument passed in is valid or not.  If you need a string and the developer passes in a number and a numeric string is a reasonable input for the function, then I don't see why you should not just use Javascript's string conversion automatically and let things go.

Javascript developers like type checking when it helps them identify a mistake they've made.  Javascript developers don't like type checking when it's just being pedantic and an auto or explicit type-conversion would have worked just fine.

Also keep in mind that you should rarely insist that a passed object is a particular type of object (say using `instanceof`) because it should be perfectly valid to pass any object that works like the expected object.  For example, a `promise` in Javascript can pretty much be any object that has the desired methods that follow the proper specification.  It does not have to be one particular type of object class with one particular constructor.

Javascript isn't a strongly typed language and there really is no reason to try to make it behave like it is something that it isn't.  Check types when that's required for the proper operation of your code, not because you're trying to make Javascript behave as strictly as Java.  I wouldn't suggest adding type checking just because you think all languages should have type checking.  If that's your line of thinking, then perhaps you should write in TypeScript or something like that that adds type specification to the language.

Comment: +1 for                                                                        "*Check types when that's required for the proper operation of your code*"

Comment: Thank you! Super informative and hit all the questions perfectly. I have looked into TypeScript and will play with it more I'm sure, but it does make sense that type checking when it has an explicit purpose and not kicking up a fuss for certain invalid types when they can be cheaply casting it to a valid type. I knew something about "JavaScript is what it is, use it" would come up but this just reiterates the importance of that to me. Thank you again!